# How come Google Cloud Build trigger can't find custom named .yaml files?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, build-triggers

## The Problem

When using, *cloudbuild.yaml* files, specifically named for their build environment, such as *[cloudbuild-dev.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLOVT.png)* and *cloudbuild-prod.yaml*, and configured/targeted in the Trigger settings they aren't found/recognized when GCB reacts to a GitHub event (push etc).

[image]

However, it's working just fine when manually running the Trigger from [GCB console](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/triggers).

When using an ordinarily named *cloudbuild.yaml*, in the root of the project, Cloud Build correctly runs the expected steps.

### The Workaround

In short, there isn't an easy one (imo). But to get it run you need to use just a single _cloudbuild.yaml).

However, to effectively re-use that for both dev and prod environments one is blocked by this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423477/how-do-i-get-google-cloud-build-to-properly-substitute-values-when-it-responds-t)

Comment: Could you please check if the issue still persists?

Comment: Did you change the value of field `Cloud Build configuration file location` when you configure your trigger ?